# Problem When Deploying Sveltekit Project to Vercel

Tags: javascript, firebase, svelte, vercel, sveltekit

So I Was trying to deploy my Sveltekit app with Vercel but this happened:

```
Cloning completed: 221.226ms
Previous build cache not available
Using prebuilt build artifacts...
Error: Config file was not found at "/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/config.json"
at P8 (/var/task/sandbox.js:315:2645)
```

My svelte.config.js file:

```
import vercel from '@sveltejs/adapter-vercel'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
kit: {
    adapter: vercel()
}
};

export default config;
```

As you can see I do have the adapter for Vercel imported and in use. So what is the Problem Here? I can figure it out

My build command is:  pnpm run build
My output directory is: .svelte-kit
My install command is: pnpm install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output directory should be left blank (or set to `.`), not `.svelte-kit` — that's a place for SvelteKit to do its work, it's of no concern to Vercel.

Comment: Thank you Rich Harris it works! And Umm thank you For the Awesome Framework I love this!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, but I didn't change the output directory.